# Inapp Purchase is succeeded but content is not unlock in iPhone app.. Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

In My iphone app i have used In App purchase. All the things are working and the contents are in Resource folder. After successful transaction i have used a Sql Query to insert data in Sqlite database. I have Uploaded this app in App Store and find that after successful transaction the payment is taken from users but the content is not inserted in database and not Showed  in app. Please help me. i am stressed on this Point. Due to this i have removed my app form App Store.

In this code after successful finding list of In App Purchases i am using method

For better Understanding i am putting my Some code here:

```
- (void)insertNewObject {

    // Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        // NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}


-(void)updateObject {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        abort();
    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Store request

- (void) requestProductData {
    request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:[arrayProductID objectAtIndex:b-2]]];//@"Scaringmirror11"
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

- (void) startPurchase {
    //int newB=b-2;
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:[arrayProductID objectAtIndex:b-2]];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}



#pragma mark Store delegate
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    if (myProduct == nil || [myProduct count] == 0) 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE message:@"Missing product from App store.\n"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }
    SKProduct *product;
    BOOL    existProduct = NO;
    for (int i=0; i<[myProduct count]; i++) {
        product = (SKProduct*)[myProduct objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[arrayProductID objectAtIndex:b-2]]) {
            existProduct = YES;

            //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"proUpgradeTransactionReceipt" ];
            //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (existProduct == NO) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE message:@"Missing product from App store.No match Identifier found.\n"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }

    [request autorelease];
    [self startPurchase];
}



#pragma mark Store delegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    if (myProduct == nil || [myProduct count] == 0) 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE message:@"Missing product from App store.\n"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }
    SKProduct *product;
    BOOL    existProduct = NO;
    for (int i=0; i<[myProduct count]; i++) {
        product = (SKProduct*)[myProduct objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[arrayProductID objectAtIndex:b-2]]) {
            existProduct = YES;

            //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"proUpgradeTransactionReceipt" ];
            //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (existProduct == NO) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE message:@"Missing product from App store.No match Identifier found.\n"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }

    [request autorelease];
    [self startPurchase];
}


#pragma mark observer delegate
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Success");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Failed");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:REGISTRATION_KEY];
    registered = YES;

    //NSData *receiptData = [transaction transactionReceipt];

    //NSString *str =[NSString string 
    //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"proUpgradeTransactionReceipt" ];
    //[self registeredEnable];
    // Remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    [sqlite insertIntoScaryImage:[arrayGetMoreScaryImage objectAtIndex:b] add:[arrayGetMoreScarySound objectAtIndex:b]];
}

- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:REGISTRATION_KEY];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE message:@"Purchase success."
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

    //[sq];
}

- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        // Optionally, display an error here.
        NSString *stringError = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Payment Cancelled\n\n%@", [transaction.error localizedDescription]];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE message:stringError
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Please have a look and tell me where should i insert data in database so that i will able to provide data to users after Successful in app Purchase.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your unlocking functionality into the payment observer, right after you receive confirmation that the payment is all right.
Your implementation of the observer is kinda strange, I guess it's not working.

EDIT:

your observer class

```
#import Foundation/Foundation.h
#import StoreKit/StoreKit.h


@interface InAppPurchaseObserver : NSObject  {

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions;

@end

#import "InAppPurchaseObserver.h"


@implementation InAppPurchaseObserver

// The transaction status of the SKPaymentQueue is sent here.
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                // Item is still in the process of being purchased
                NSLog(@"Processing!!!");
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                // Item was successfully purchased!

                // --- UNLOCK FEATURE OR DOWNLOAD CONTENT HERE ---
                // The purchased item ID is accessible via 
                // transaction.payment.productIdentifier



                // After customer has successfully received purchased content,
                // remove the finished transaction from the payment queue.
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                // Verified that user has already paid for this item.
                // Ideal for restoring item across all devices of this customer.

                // --- UNLOCK FEATURE OR DOWNLOAD CONTENT HERE ---
                // The purchased item ID is accessible via 
                // transaction.payment.productIdentifier


                // After customer has restored purchased content on this device,
                // remove the finished transaction from the payment queue.
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                // Purchase was either cancelled by user or an error occurred.
                NSLog(@"Failed!!!");


                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    // A transaction error occurred, so notify user.
                    NSLog(@"Cancelled!!!");
                }
                // Finished transactions should be removed from the payment queue.
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

implementation

```
- (void) requestProductData {

    inappObserver = [[InAppPurchaseObserver alloc] init];

    request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:[arrayProductID objectAtIndex:b-2]]];//@"Scaringmirror11"
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

- (void) startPurchase {
    //int newB=b-2;
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:[arrayProductID objectAtIndex:b-2]];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:inappObserver];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

Comment: Yes... Its Not working. Do u mean fire Query In Observer Delegate method when check the Case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased  ?

Comment: The best you can do is create separate class where you store just observer delegate. Then allocate the observer and add to in app payment, very easy. I will post code in sec.

Comment: Hi... i know the purchased item id because this is within app... so may i need it again to fetch from process ?

Comment: Not sure why. In most cases the solution I have  posted above works just fine. The observer itself handles all transaction very well.

Comment: No I mean was i am entering all data in sqlite and i know that data id which will enter in database at some purchase. Because for every purchase i need to store this data in sqlite..